# What are fragments when using youtube-dl program?

Tags: download, youtube, youtube-dl

I am using [`youtube-dl` program](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) to get some videos from Youtube.
Some files appear in Windows File Explorer while downloading.
For example:

[image]

Command line program also shows that exist a total amount of fragments in that video:

[image]

And command line help in `youtube-dl` also gives some download options relative to fragments:

[image]

Fragments seem like small chunks of video parts.
But, is there a better technical explanation?

Answer (score 1):

According to what the source code of youtube-dl [fragment.py file](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/downloader/fragment.py#L22) shows, a fragment would be a:

> **fragmented media** like **[f4m](https://fileinfo.com/extension/f4m)**/**[m3u8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#M3U8)** manifests

Which point to some *manifest* or stream format for [Flash Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) and [HTTP Live Streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming).

Comment: Do you know what's up with skipped fragments? Like what causes a fragment to be skipped and is there any way to retry a skipped fragment? Also if a video finishes with some skipped fragments then is it incomplete/missing segments?

Comment: Honestly, no idea... May be you can ask in youtube-dl Github repository.
If you create an issue, there is an option to `Ask question`:
https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/new/choose